# Accumulo BatchWriter close() stuck forever

Tags: java, accumulo

For example, when I use BatchWriter to write into accumulo, I use the code as follows:

```
BatchWriter writer =
    conn.createBatchWriter("table", memBuf, timeout, numThreads)

writer.add(mutation);
writer.close();
```

I figured out that the java code stuck in "writer.close()" when I have "writer.add(mutation)". But when I remove "writer.add(mutation);", it went through "writer.close()". Does anyone know how to solve the BatchWriter close() problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Accumulo monitor for errors. If you only add one mutation, it will be sent to the servers when you close the BatchWriter (mutations are batched together for performance reasons). Your client is likely waiting on a response from at least one TabletServer.

You can also collect a stackdump from your client and from your tabletserver(s), showing where the code is currently stuck (using `jstack` for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, my coworker said better check the tserver logs and it definitely helps. My issue was that I had a bad table in accumulo. When I try to write mutation to it, it just hangs and had no logs put in the console. After deleting the bad table and creating the new one, the problem solved.

Comment: Weird, what version of Accumulo? If you still have the Accumulo logs, feel free to send us a note at user@accumulo.apache.org or create an issue on our JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACCUMULO

Comment: My version is 1.6.5. I checked the tserver logs, actually I didn't find anything related to the bad table. When the table was bad, it just went silent, which is not a good thing...I cannot see any exceptions in my console, neither error or warns related to that bad table in accumulo monitor or tserver logs. Hopefully that helps you to improve accumulo :)

Answer (score 3):

(Note: Not enough rep. to add as comment)

An additional debugging tip: Using the accumulo shell you can turn on debug mode (type `debug` in the accumulo shell); then you can try a manual insertion of the key or even just a simple scan of the row you are trying to insert into.  The debug info will print out the sequence of servers accumulo is communicating with to execute your commands. This can quickly point you to the host machine which is having a problem.